# What is the software to download for make a bootable USB drive from Ubuntu studio 20.04 (XFCE)?

Tags: live-usb, ubuntu-studio

I want to know what software should I install for making a bootable USB drive from Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (XFCE)?

I didn't find any stock software that can make it.
There is a Gnome disk, but it's for Gnome.

Comment: Xfce is a GTK3 desktop, as is GNOME, so using `gnome-disk-utility` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/gnome-disk-utility) is not wrong; it just may not look as native as it's using GNOME specific appearance settings or *window dressing*.  From the command line `dd` is of course available; but it's a risky tool

Comment: CD to folder with the ISO file and run dd: `sudo dd if=ubuntustudio-20.04.3-dvd-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1024k` where **ubuntustudio-20.04.3-dvd-amd64.iso** is the full name of the ISO file and **/dev/sdx** is the USB. With dd the slightest typo can wipe your hdd. Both Archisman Panigrahi and guiverc's methods are safer but require downloads.

Comment: You have left a couple important parts unanswered: 1) What OS are you currently running? 2) What are you going to use the USB for: installing Ubuntu Studio or as a portable OS, or for both. You can make a Live install, a Full install or a Persistent install. Each method is different. Some people even want a clone of their desktop on a USB that will run on any computer, which is also possible.

Answer (score 6):

You can install USB Creator with

```
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

Then open it from the Whisker Menu.

Alternatively, click [here](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.5.122/balena-etcher-electron-1.5.122-linux-x64.zip?d_id=af532bbd-85d7-4fac-b148-5fd683fc5d78R) to download [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). It is available in a click to run format (appimage).

[image: Balena Etcher]
 <sup>Balena Etcher</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you can search for **Rufus**. It is free and easily downloadable.

If you are using **Ubuntu** there is an already installed software called **Startup Disk Creator**

Comment: The Startup Disk Creator is available in standard Ubuntu Desktop and some other community flavours, but not in UbuntuStudio. But it is easy to install it. as described in another answer to this question.

Comment: The Startup Disk Creator is by default available in Ubuntu Studio. I use Ubuntu Studio. Maybe I am mismatching versions, but I am on the edge 21.10

Comment: I do not find the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (the OP asks about that version). But I find it in 20.10 and in the current daily Impish iso file (as you have already noted). I'm glad that the Ubuntu Studio team has added it to the iso file in the newer versions. Anyway, I already upvoted your answer :-)